# Convex combination of product states cannot be purified to a product state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, linear-algebra, quantum-states

Suppose we have two distinct states $\rho,\sigma\in \mathcal{H}_A$. Define the following state

$$\omega = \frac{1}{2}(\rho^{\otimes n} + \sigma^{\otimes n}) \in \mathcal{H}_A^n$$

Let $\mathcal{H}_R\cong \mathcal{H}_A$ and let $n$ copies of $\mathcal{H}_R$ be used to purify $\omega$. After playing around a bit, I think it holds that the purification $\vert\Psi\rangle_{A^nR^n}$ cannot be expressed as some $\vert\psi\rangle_{AR}^{\otimes n}$. I believe even if $|R|>|A|$ is allowed, this still cannot be done i.e. the purification space can be arbitrarily large but the product state structure cannot be acheived for the purification.

**EDIT**

To put it more precisely, prove that the following statement is false.

> For all quantum states of the form $\omega = \frac{1}{2}(\rho^{\otimes
>   n} + \sigma^{\otimes n}) \in \mathcal{H}_A^n$, there exists a pure
>   product state $\vert\psi\rangle^{\otimes n}_{AR}\in \mathcal{H}^n_{AR}$ such that
>   $\text{Tr}_{R^n}(\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert^{\otimes n}_{AR}) = \omega$.

On a related note, when is the product state purification possible? For instance, when $\rho = \sigma$, $\omega = \rho^{\otimes n}$ and now, there is a product state that purifies $\omega$. Is there a weaker condition on $\rho$ and $\sigma$ that still allows the purification to be a product state?

> If $\rho$ and $\sigma$ satisfy ... , there exists a state a pure
>   product state $\vert\psi\rangle^{\otimes n}_{AR}\in
>   \mathcal{H}^n_{AR}$ such that
>   $\text{Tr}_{R^n}(\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert^{\otimes n}_{AR}) =
>  \omega$.

Comment: Can you please phrase this in a more precise way, i.e. make clear the order of "there exists psi", "for all N", "given some N", and so on?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I have edited. I hope the question is clearer now?

Comment: Does my answer answer it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be true - assuming that I understand the question correctly - since for instance, for $\rho=|0\rangle\langle0|$ and $\sigma=|1\rangle\langle1|$, the measurement outcomes on all $n$ qubits in $\omega$ are perfectly correlated.

On the other hand, on any purification of the form $|\psi\rangle_{AR}^{\otimes n}$, the measurement outcomes on the $A$ systems are entirely uncorrelated.

I'm sure this can be turned into a quantitative argument as well.

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice argument. If I understand correctly, you have also reduced my question to the following: When is a convex combination of product states itself a product state?

Comment: @user1936752 I guess so.  In any case, the convex combination of product state reminds me of the quantum de Finetti theorem, in case this is relevant for you.